# how to download an excel file in react from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a nodeJs server and react app. and in my NodeJs I am returning an excel file and I was able to download it in postman when clicking send and download. But in react the file is download but give error when openning that it is corrupt

Here is my implementation in ReactJS (Thats making the issue)

```
export const exportUsersToExcel = async (token) => {
      try {
        axios
          .get(
            `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER}/api/dashboard/users/excel`,
            {
              headers: { "auth-token": token },
            },
            { responseType: "blob" }
          )
          .then((response) => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
            const link = document.createElement("a");
            link.href = url;
            link.setAttribute("download", "Users.xlsx");
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error Exporting Users");
        return error;
      }
    };
```

and I am sending the file in NodeJS like this

```
    res.set({
      "Content-disposition": `attachment; filename=Users.xlsx`,
      "Content-Type":
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    });

    return workbook.xlsx.write(res).then(() => {
      res.status(200).end();
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, and I solved it with the following (React) code:

Axios

```
export const getFile = async () => {
  return await api.get<any>(`${PATH_API}`, {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'blob'},
  });
};
```

Function in .tsx file

```
const downloadFile = async () => {
    const resp = await getFile();

    const link = document.createElement('a');
    const fileName = 'file.extension';
    link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([resp.data]));
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.remove();
  };
```

Render function

```
<a onClick={() => downloadExceptionFile()} href="#" download>
download
</a>
```

The ploblem with this is that `URL.createObjectURL()` is deprecated. I don't know how to resolve this at this point.